# Is a hammer used "for driving in" nails, or "to drive in" nails?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Expressing the function of a thing requires "for doing":

> A hammer is **for driving in** nails.

Expressing the intention of a person requires "to do":

> I need a hammer **to drive in** those nails.

If you add "used" to the first sentence (introducing the person), which structure should you use?

> A hammer is used **for driving in** nails.

**or**

> A hammer is used **to drive in** nails.

Comment: Either is acceptable.

Comment: ...or *A knife is used to cut.* Just as I am used to going to be late.

Comment: Curious that I seldom hear "**drive in nails**", usually it's "**hammer in nails**".

Comment: @Mari-LouA: the question is what happens when you add "used", that is, when you add a person (the implied agent of an implied passive verb form, is used by someone)? Does the 'for doing' structure make sense or should you switch to the 'to do' structure, since a person has been introduced and their intention might have precedence over function of the thing, if you see what I mean...?

Comment: @user58319 "**I need a nail to hang a picture with**" and "**I need nails for hanging pictures with**" in both cases the sentences are grammatical and introduced by a person.

Comment: See this [EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204442/clauses-of-purpose-for-ing-or-to-infinitive) (now closed), and this website http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/gerund3b.html, and http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-gerunds-and-infinitives-for-purpose/ But I see now why you thought it mattered whether a person was mentioned or not. In both websites, the TO + INFINITIVE examples are introduced by "I use it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that *"A hammer is used for driving in nails"*  is  focused on what the tool is basically designed for. Designed for the purpose of delivering an impulsive force by striking, a hammer is an ideal tool *for driving in nails*.

At the same time a hammer is not the only thing to drive in a nail with—anything with a heavy rigid surface can be used to do this—for example, a brick or a dumbbell, or whatever heavy made of steal.

So, to use something to do something is focused on *what you are using in particular* to complete your task. For example, a fork is normally used for serving and eating food. But you may use it to make an extra hole in your belt, or you may use a pencil to stir sugar into your coffee.

For example:

*I couldn't find a hammer around the house and started looking for something to drive that nail in*

Answer (score 1):

**What's it for?**  (focus on instrument)
for + VERB + ING

> A hammer is for driving in nails.

**Why do you use it?**   (focus on person)

USE + Object + TO + INFINITIVE

> I use a hammer to drive in nails

(The scheme above is copied from the [Grammar-Quizzes](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/gerund3b.html) website)

However, the FOR + V + ING construction is also possible with a person, and the verb “use”

> I **use** this hammer **for forging** metal

The Wikipedia article on [hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer#Hammer_as_a_force_amplifier) explains

> Most hammers are hand tools **used to drive** nails, fit parts, forge metal, and break apart objects.

*[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hammer)* defines hammer using the TO + INFINITIVE

> A hammer is a tool that consists of a heavy piece of metal at the end of a handle. **It is used**, for example, **to hit nails** into a piece of wood or a wall, or **to break things** into pieces.

From *The Garden Primer*, written by Barbara Damrosch

[image]

> *Round Point Shovel* […] **I use it for turning** soil over, **for making** planting holes with rounded sides, **for removing** dirt that I've loosened with some other tool such as a fork or spade, and **for filling** in the dirt after I've put a tree or shrub into the hole.

I hope this clears up the OP's confusion

<sub>It's a pity we can't wrap or position text beside small images.</sub>